User input string(path) from STDIN is not working for WalkDir
I try to collect the directory from the user and then pass it to WalkDir to get all files inside, but it did not work. Same input was working when I hard code it. I was testing it on a Windows system.
This did not work, just return nothing.
let mut some_dir = String::new(); 

io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut some_dir)
    .expect("Invalid Input");

some_dir = some_dir.replace("\\", "\\\\"); 

for entry in WalkDir::new(&some_dir).into_iter().filter_map(|file| file.ok()) {
    println!("{}", entry.path().display());
}

This worked
for entry in WalkDir::new("<dir>").into_iter().filter_map(|file| file.ok()) {
    println!("{}", entry.path().display());
}

What is the reason behind and how to fix it?

If you did the .replace with the assumption that double slashes ("\") was what you had to do for Windows paths since they are needed in to specify it in your source code (i.e. "C:\\Users\\<name>\\My Documents\\") then you should know that is only because string literals in code use "" as as escape character so you need two (to "escape" the escape character) to write a single slash. But I assure you that a single slash is correct and isn't (often) a concern outside of source code.

Two mistakes:

some_dir = some_dir.replace("\\", "\\\\"); makes no sense. Remove it.
some_dir contains \r\n. Remove it by calling .trim():

use std::io;

use walkdir::WalkDir;

fn main() {
    let mut some_dir = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut some_dir).expect("Invalid Input");

    some_dir = some_dir.trim().to_string();

    for entry in WalkDir::new(&some_dir)
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|file| file.ok())
    {
        println!("{}", entry.path().display());
    }
}


Or, a little more optimized (one less string copy):
use std::io;

use walkdir::WalkDir;

fn main() {
    let mut some_dir = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut some_dir).expect("Invalid Input");

    let some_dir = some_dir.trim();

    for entry in WalkDir::new(some_dir)
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|file| file.ok())
    {
        println!("{}", entry.path().display());
    }
}

